# SQL query to get count values of ID's where ID count >1 for the last 14 trailing months grouped by each month

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have a user_details table where each login is added. I am developing a page to view login counts like >1 and >10 etc for each ID and for each month trailing to the previous 12 months.

The following was my query to get the count for last 30 days:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ( select intClientId from tbl_pi_userdetails where LoginTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY  group by intClientId HAVING COUNT(intClientId) = 1)tbl_pi_userdetails
```

Similarly want it for trailing 14 months.

```
select
  date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago month), "%b %Y") as month,
  count(intClientId) as count
from(
    select
      months_ago,
      date(date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago month), 
      "%Y-%m-01")) start_date,
      date(date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago-1 month),
      "%Y-%m-01")) end_date
          from (select 0 months_ago union select 1 union select 2 union select 
          3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union 
          select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 
          12 union select 13 order by months_ago) months_ago
) date_range left join tbl_pi_userdetails on LoginTime >= start_date and
LoginTime < end_date and
LoginTime <= now()  group by intClientId, months_ago, 
intClientId having count(intClientId) = 1;
```

My table looks like this with different ID's and login time.
[image]

Expected results:
[image]

Comment: Could you please show your table and the SQL you have written so far? :)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Read [mcve] before you start.

Comment: I have posted the query above.

Comment: I would refer you again to jarlh's comment

Comment: @Prabhudeva M What do you mean by trailing ? Sliding? or in intervals ?

Comment: I mean the previous 14 months Ie; jan 2020, Dec 2019, Nov 2019 etc.

Comment: @ Prabhudeva M Any chance for a `create statement` ?

Comment: Im not sure about that. @MenelaosBakopoulos

Comment: @ Prabhudeva M  do you want the filter to be : >1 over 14 last months? Or >1 over each month?

Comment: I wanted it to be for each month.

Comment: @Prabhudeva M Answered.

Answer (score 0):

### Expected Results

```
select  month_year, count(*)  from
(select DATE_FORMAT(LoginTime, '%Y-%m') as month_year, count(intClientId), intClientId
from tbl_pi_userdetails where 
LoginTime >=  now() - INTERVAL 15 MONTH
group by DATE_FORMAT(LoginTime, '%Y-%m'), intClientId  having count(intClientId)> 1
order by DATE_FORMAT(LoginTime, '%Y-%m'), intClientId ) results
group by month_year 
order by month_year desc;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SLYF45hyWLQaokjDz2AAR/5

Comment: The result for the query gave me the total number of login count for each ID. My requirement was just how many ID's have count more than one for each month. Ex: 10 ID's with more than 1 count out of 15 ID's for jan 2020. Jan 2020 - 10 Counts

Comment: Just change having `count(intClientId)> 0 to >1` . Updated @Prabhudeva M

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SLYF45hyWLQaokjDz2AAR/3 - The following query worked exactly how I wanted to work. Thank a million.

Comment: There is another complication here. I need to count has 0 for the months for which the results are not available.